# Using generic interfaces and classes

Tags: java, generics

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
```

I am trying to make a generic interface and a class that implements it. This is the interface:

```
interface UpdateDBListener<T> {
    void onUpdateSuccess(T person);
    void onUpdateFailure(String errMessage);
}
void updatePerson(T person, UpdateDBListener updateDBListener);
```

Error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getId() where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class PeopleListModelImp
```

And this is the class that implements it:

```
public class PeopleListModelImp<T> implements PeopleListModelContract<T> {

@Override
public void updatePerson(T person, UpdateDBListener updateListener) {
    String id = person.getId(); /* ERROR */
}
```

The class I am using to pass in in this:

```
public class Person {
    String mId;
    String mFirstName;
    String mLastName;

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.mId = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.mFirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.mLastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

However, if I try to get the Id in the class that implements the interface I get an error on this line:

```
String id = person.getId();
```

I think as person don't know its a Person class, so doesn't understand the getId(). I am just wondering I am doing this an incorrect way. I want the class to be completely generic so I can using it for other different classes.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `"I get an error on this line:..."` -- what error? You've been here long enough to know to post this key bit of information, the complete error message, no?

Comment: Also, your interface and the interface implemented by the class are completely different?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?
Can I see your main() method?

Comment: In the future, please try to condense your code into a valid [mcve] as it will save the volunteers trying to help much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to change

```
public class PeopleListModelImp<T> implements PeopleListModelContract<T> {
```

to

```
public class PeopleListModelImp<T extends Person> implements PeopleListModelContract<T> {
```

So that T knows that it's either a Person or a sub-class of Person.

---

Also, shouldn't

```
public void updatePerson(final T person, final UpdateDBListener updateListener) {
```

be changed to

```
public void updatePerson(final T person, final UpdateDBListener<T> updateListener) {
```

so that the method doesn't lose its genericity?

Note that in the future, you'll want to condense your code into a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it's easier for the volunteers here to answer. Your posted code for instance did not include the PeopleListModelContract.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was missing Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009; you're welcome, and sorry to complain, but your question could have been made better. Please see comments. Your help with this in future questions would be greatly appreciated by the volunteers who help here.

Comment: I am grateful for the comments you gave and the help that you gave that was needed to solve the problem. I am just getting started with generics and this will help.

Comment: Just a follow up question. Currently I am using a Person class. However, If I wanted to use another i.e. class Employee. Could I make this generic enough to use any class without changing any of the code signatures?

Comment: @ant2009 Since T *extends* Person, it will work with any class that extends Person. See [generic tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)